# Error al enlazar manualmente: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file

Tags: gcc, enlazado

Últimamente estoy construyendo un sistema operativo en ensamblador (bootloader) y C (kernel). Acabo de terminar de escribir el kernel para pasar a modo protegido de 32 bits, y he decidido ponerme a hacer pruebas con C para ver como se compilaba en ensamblador.

Mientras hacia estas pruebas he usado las siguientes herramientas:

- Sistema operativo: Windows 7, Arquitectura: x86
- MinGW: GCC para compilar y LD para 'linkear' el código objeto
- NASM: NDISASM para obtener el código fuente en ensamblador

Lo primero que hice fue escribir el código fuente en C (`basic.c`):

```
int main(){
    return 0xbaba;
}
```

Después compilé con `gcc -ffreestanding -c basic.c -o basic.o`, y obtuve el archivo `basic.o` con código objeto.

Después, intenté usar el siguiente comando para 'linkear' el código fuente:

```
ld -o basic.bin -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary basic.o
```

Pero obtuve el siguiente error:

```
ld: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file 'basic.bin'.
```

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe?

Comment: Vale, encontré una respuesta en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary/1647405#1647405